# How to get href link from in this a tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I successfully get href link from http://quotes.toscrape.com/ example by implementing:

```
response.css('div.quote > span > a::attr(href)').extract()
```

and it gives all partial link inside href of each a tag:

```
['/author/Albert-Einstein', '/author/J-K-Rowling', '/author/Albert-Einstein', '/author/Jane-Austen', '/author/Marilyn-Monroe', '/author/Albert-Einstein', '/author/Andre-Gide', '/author/Thomas-A-Edison', '/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt', '/author/Steve-Martin']
```

by the way in above example each a tag has this format:

```
<a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
```

So I tried to make the same for this site: http://www.thegoodscentscompany.com/allproc-1.html
The problem here is that the style of a tag is a bit different as such:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openMainWindow('http://www.thegoodscentscompany.com/data/rw1247381.html');return false;">formaldehyde</a>
```

As you see I can't get link from href by using similar method above. I want to get link (http://www.thegoodscentscompany.com/data/rw1247381.html) from this a tag, but i could not make it. How can i get this link?

Comment: A rather naive approach that might work could be: `response.xpath('//a/@onclick').re(r"openMainWindow\('(.*?)'\)")` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is the issue, exactly?

Comment: @Jon Clements, it worked thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `response.css('a::attr(onclick)').re(r"Window\('(.*?)'\)")`